# How to get the lowest value from a JSON array with PHP

Tags: php, json

I am trying to loop through a JSON multidimensional array and get the lowest `distance` value for each shop and print it along with the `location_id` value.

I can't get any further than what I have here. I've tried a million options by searching through stackoverflow but just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My JSON data is like this:

```
$json = '{
  "shops": [
   {
      "shop_id": "100",
          "locations": [
                { "location_id": "100_1", "distance": "10.3" },
                { "location_id": "100_2", "distance": "15.2" }
          ]
    },
    {
      "shop_id": "101",
          "locations": [
                { "location_id": "101_1", "distance": "19.3" },
                { "location_id": "101_2", "distance": "12.4" }
          ]
    }]
}';
```

Right now, the code I have is:

```
// Decode the JSON data
$json_data = json_decode($json,true);

// Do a foreach loop
foreach($json_data['shops'] as $shops){

echo $shops['shop_id'].', ';

// Currently prints:
// 101, 102 ,

// But I need it to print:
// 100_1 -> 10.3, 101_2 -> 12.4

}
```

I tried putting another foreach loop into the existing one but that just prints a `1`.

How do I achieve that? I can't wrap my head around it. I need the lowest `distance` value printed for each of the `['shop_id']['locations']`

Comment: There is no such thing as a "JSON array" or "JSON object". [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of a data structure (that can be an array, an object but also a number or a string). In order to process the data, the JSON needs to be parsed and this produces a data structure identical to the one used to generate the JSON. That data structure is not JSON any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract all the distances for a particular shop and then use `min` on that array to get the lowest value. To also get the location, we then use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the minimum key with that value and use that to get the appropriate `location_id` for the store:

```
foreach($json_data['shops'] as $shops) {
    $distances = array_column($shops['locations'], 'distance');
    $locations = array_column($shops['locations'], 'location_id');
    $min = min($distances);
    $location = array_search($min, $distances);
    echo $locations[$location] . ' -> ' . $min . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
100_1 -> 10.3 
101_2 -> 12.4
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/PvdEk)

**Update**

As @Andreas has pointed out in the comments, we can use the third parameter to `array_column` to get an array of distances with their `location_id` as the key. We can then sort the array and use [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) and [`key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) to get the minimum distance and corresponding location:

```
foreach($json_data['shops'] as $shops) {
    $distances = array_column($shops['locations'], 'distance', 'location_id');
    asort($distances);
    echo key($distances) . ' -> ' . current($distances) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
100_1 -> 10.3 
101_2 -> 12.4
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/eI29a)

Comment: They want the `location_id` element - so `100_1 -> 10.3`

Comment: OMG, I can't believe how simple that is. But yes, I need the `location_id`, but that's amazingly close to the result I need. I tried to do `$shops['locations']['location_id']` but that didn't work.

Comment: I see you updated your reply. And it works fantastically. Thank you so much for saving my day. Will accept your reply as fast as it allows me :)

Comment: @moomoo I've updated my answer to give the location as well

Comment: @moomoo I edited again with a better version that uses the `location_id` values as it should.

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for pointing that out I had not noticed originally

Comment: You could also do an array_column with the third parameter and asort() the array, then just echo the first item. https://3v4l.org/0PMut

Comment: @Andreas I *always* forget that third parameter to `array_column`! Thanks for suggesting it - I've updated the answer with a solution based on that.

Comment: I have already upvoted. But I see you use key() and current(). I recently ran in to issues using those functions. Can't remember what the cause/problem was but I could not use key(). I see that it works for you. Strange.

Comment: @Andreas I appreciate that. If you recall what issues you had with `key` I'd be interested. It should work fine after anything such as `asort` that resets the array.

Comment: That could have been the deal. I had not done anything to the array. The pointer was not set somewhere. Is that even possible.

Comment: @Andreas that is a good question; I think it should always be set somewhere, but I don't know for certain. There are so many things you can do to arrays... something like `array_splice` or `unset` might screw up the pointer if it was pointing at an element that got removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sub-loops, to try and pick out the lowest distance.  Easier to follow the code and to construct a resulting array:

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "shops": [
   {
        "shop_id": "100",
        "locations": [
            { "location_id": "100_1", "distance": "10.3" },
            { "location_id": "100_2", "distance": "15.2" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "shop_id": "101",
        "locations": [
            { "location_id": "101_1", "distance": "19.3" },
            { "location_id": "101_2", "distance": "12.4" }
        ]
    }]
}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);

$min_distances = [];
foreach($data['shops'] as $shop)
{
    $distance = null;
    foreach($shop['locations'] as $location)
    {
        if(is_null($distance) || $location['distance'] < $distance)
        {
            $distance = $location['distance'];
            $location_id  = $location['location_id'];
        }
    }
    $min_distances[] = [
        'shop_id'=>$shop['shop_id'], 
        'distance'=>$distance, 
        'location_id'=>$location_id
    ];
}
var_dump($min_distances);
```

Output:

```
 array(2) {
[0]=>
array(3) {
    ["shop_id"]=>
    string(3) "100"
    ["distance"]=>
    string(4) "10.3"
    ["location_id"]=>
    string(5) "100_1"
}
[1]=>
array(3) {
    ["shop_id"]=>
    string(3) "101"
    ["distance"]=>
    string(4) "12.4"
    ["location_id"]=>
    string(5) "101_2"
}
}
```