# Get lowest Value from JSON API response in PHP

Tags: php, json

Below an API response from a courier company, using PHP I am trying to get the lowest rate by company_code. How could i do that. Had tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511606/how-to-get-the-lowest-value-from-a-json-array-with-php) but did't work form me.

```
{
   "Status":"00",
   "Message":"Successful",
   "couriersRate":[
      {
         "rate":"7.00",
         "name":"CJ Century Logistics Holdings Berhad",
         "company_code":"cj"
      },
      {
         "rate":"9.56",
         "name":"Poslaju Sdn Bhd",
         "company_code":"poslaju"
      },
      {
         "rate":"6.78",
         "name":"Skynet Worldwide1",
         "company_code":"skynet"
      }
   ]
}
```

what i have tried the following code to get the expected result

```
    <?php
$json = '{
  "Status": "00",
  "Message": "Successful",
  "couriersRate": [
    {
      "rate": "7.00",
      "name": "CJ Century Logistics Holdings Berhad",
      "company_code": "cj"
    },
    {
      "rate": "9.56",
      "name": "Poslaju Sdn Bhd",
      "company_code": "poslaju"
    },
    {
      "rate": "6.78",
      "name": "Skynet Worldwide1",
      "company_code": "skynet"
    }
  ]
}';



$json_data = json_decode($json, true); 

for ($i = 0; $i < count($json_data['couriersRate']); $i++) {

  $rate=$json_data['couriersRate'][$i]['rate'];
  $min = min(array($rate));

}

echo $rate;
```

**UPDATE**
Below code worked form me
https://3v4l.org/thnTV
thanks @GNassro

Comment: edit your post and show us what you try

Comment: I have added my code, however after going through a for loop i was able to get the expected lowest rate. but i want the company_code belongs to that rate instead, which is "skynet" in this case

Comment: maybe this simple code will help you https://3v4l.org/thnTV

Comment: wow thats worked, thanks